# How to Check if a String Contains a Second String with its Characters in Order?

Tags: java, string

I'm just starting out and I'm completely lost on how to do this.

I want to be able to check a string for a smaller string and return true if the string contains the letters of the string in order.

I'm not sure how to go about making sure the letters of the second string are in order, even if there are other letters between them.

An example would be that "chemistry" would return true for the string "hit".

It would return false for the string "him" though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you, I changed the word "substring" to string. As I said, I'm just beginning and wasn't aware that meant something else. I really appreciate all the help. It should get me moving in the right direction.

Comment: You may have noticed that a number of answers and comments have misunderstood your question. The reason for this is that the term "substring" actually has a very standard meaning, and that this very standard meaning is *not* the same as what you mean. (Of course, if they read your question more carefully, they would realize that you don't mean what they think.)

Comment: Thank you, I changed it. I apologize to everyone for that.

Comment: no effort shown and seven upvotes?!?

Comment: @lockstock It is in an interesting problem set.

Answer (score 6):

The general approach is to iterate over the characters of the longer string ("chemistry"), always keeping track of the index of the next required character from the shorter string ("hit" — first 0, then 1 once you find `h`, then 2 once you find `i`, and then when you find `t` you're done). For example:

```
public static boolean containsSubsequence(
        final String sequence, final String subsequence) {
    if (subsequence.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    int subsequenceIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); ++i) {
        if (sequence.charAt(i) == subsequence.charAt(subsequenceIndex)) {
            ++subsequenceIndex;
            if (subsequenceIndex == subsequence.length()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SInce you haven't posted any code, I will just explain what would I do.

- Iterate over all the substring letter by letter, on your example "hit"
- Check if the current letter (iterate 0 is h) is on the string, if/when it find you remove the ocurrences before it and let the string from that (emistry)
- Do this process for all left substrings
- use a control boolean variable to see if it has found or not.
- if in any pass of the iteration you did not find you return false.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could go through both strings simultaneously, advancing your index to the "substring" (the correct term is *subsequence* - "mist" is a substring of "chemistry", but "hit" is only a subsequence) string only if its current character matches the current character in the outer string. I.e., for "chemistry" and "hit", you start with indices `i = 0, j = 0`. You increase the index `i` into the first string until you encounter `s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)`, which is the case for `i = 1` (second character in chemistry is h). Then you increase `j`, and are now increasing `i` again until you hit an "i" (`i = 4`). The second string is contained as a subsequence in the first if at the end, `j == s2.length()` holds. Note that here - unlike for more complex problems, such as testing if the second string really is a *substring* - a greedy strategy works, meaning you don't have to worry about *which* of multiple occurrences of the same character you match against the current in one in the second string; you can always "greedily" choose the first one you see.

Alternatively, you can use regexes: convert the second (search) string into the regex pattern `String pat = ".*h.*i.*t.*"`, and test `s1.matches(pat)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following (not sure how efficient it is):

1. Consider your search string "hit" as an array of char: ["h","i","t"]
2. Use indexOf(c) to determine whether the first character in the array can be found.
3. Repeat the search on the remaining substring.

Here's the code:

```
public class SearchString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String searchSpace = "this is where to search?";
        String needle = "tweus?";
        char[] chars = needle.toCharArray();
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = true;
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (found && index < chars.length){
            searchSpace = searchSpace.substring(startIndex);
            startIndex = searchSpace.indexOf(chars[index]);
            found = (startIndex != -1);
            index++;
        }
        if (index==chars.length && found){
            System.out.println("Found it");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing here");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified answer based on @ruakh's solution:

```
public static boolean containsSubsequence(final String sequence, final String subsequence) {
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(sequence).isEmpty() || Objects.requireNonNull(subsequence).isEmpty() || subsequence.length() > sequence.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) {
        if (sequence.charAt(i) == subsequence.charAt(index) && ++index == subsequence.length()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Objects.requireNonNull()` is from Java 7, remember to substitute for something similar (from [Apache Commons's `StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)?) if you're not on Java 7. The validation assumes returning `false` is suitable for an empty sequence or subsequence, or you may want to consider throwing something like `IllegalArgumentException`.

The two `if` statements have been combined into a single clause for compactness.

edit:
If one is mathematically inclined, or following @ruakh's original solution, any sequence should contain an empty subsequence. The only reason why my code above is doing it differently is because I prefer to imagine an empty argument as a form of invalid argument, thus returning `false`. It really depends on how this method is used, and how 'severe' an empty argument is.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked as a Java question. But just for reference, here is a version of it in C.\

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int find_str_in_str(const char* const base, const char* const sub)
{
        int base_len = strlen(base);
        int sub_len  = strlen(sub);    
        char *tmp_sub = NULL;

        /* allocate enough mem for the max string length */
        if(base_len > sub_len) {
                tmp_sub = malloc(base_len + 1);
        } else {
                tmp_sub = malloc(sub_len + 1);
        }

        if(NULL == tmp_sub) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Runtime error (malloc)\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(; i < sub_len; i++) {
                for(; j < base_len; j++) {
                        if(base[j] == sub[i]) {
                                tmp_sub[i] = base[j];
                                /* the first occurance was found */
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        tmp_sub[i++] = '\0';

        if(0 == strcmp(sub, tmp_sub)) {
                free(tmp_sub);
                return 1;
        } else {
                free(tmp_sub);
                return 0;
        }
}





int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if(argc < 3) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s %s %s\n", argv[0], "base", "derived");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(1 == find_str_in_str(argv[1], argv[2])) {
                printf("true\n");
        } else {
                printf("false\n");
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

to compile: `gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c -o main`

`main self elf`

`main chemistry try`

`main chemistry hit`

`main chemistry tim`